# Call css property [for ex.: element.style.padding]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me. I want to call css property which is located in css file, but I get empty value.

```
<style>
#a {padding:10px;}
</style>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" style="padding:10px;"></div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById('a').style.padding);//''
alert(document.getElementById('b').style.padding);//'10px'
</script>
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/TcBnV/)

Comment: You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style & https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the shorthand property this way, but you could use this:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a"), null).getPropertyValue("padding-top"));
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcBnV/1/)

Edit to add the links from BYossarians comment:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style

> Summary:
>
> Returns an object that represents the element's style attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

> Summary:
>
> getComputedStyle() gives the values of all the CSS properties of an
>   element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic
>   computation those values may contain.

Comment: @user307340 You're welcome :-) If this answered your question, please remember to mark it as the answer, so future askers can find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because without explicitly specifying it is not 'defined' in DOM and being empty and document.getElementById is reading from DOM.

You can try with jQuery which handles all this correctly.

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" style="padding:10px;"></div>
<script>
    alert($('#a').css('padding'));//''
    alert($('#b').css('padding'));//'10px'
</script>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KoalaBear/53p8E/)

Comment: Yeah, jQuery does. But without jQuery ?

Comment: rusmus has an answer to that. Learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

check your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcBnV/2/)

you can use this

```
var stylePart = getStyle(document.getElementById("a"), "padding-right");
        alert(stylePart);

function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule) {
            var strValue = "";
            if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
                strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
            }
            else if (oElm.currentStyle) {
                strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1) {
                    return p1.toUpperCase();
                });
                strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
            }
            return strValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

alert(parseInt($('#a').css('padding')));

```
What i did:
```

1)First find out DOM element inside HTML using div ID ,get particular .

2)Then take CSS property of Div using ".css" and Which property you want(padding).

3) then parsed to int to remove PX.

Comment: Please explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Working here http://jsfiddle.net/RxfLu/1/

if you want to get padding from css/Stylesheet you need to do..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var el = $('#a');
   width = el.width(),
   padding = ((el.outerWidth()-width)/2)+"px";
   alert(padding)
});
```

and by using below you are getting the padding value from style attribute of element not from css/Stylesheet

```
alert(document.getElementById('b').style.padding);
```